# gulp watch vesrion 4.0

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I want to use gulp-watch in my project. gulp-watch is not working in my gulpfile.js.
I use gulp vesrion 4.0 in my project "gulp": "^4.0.0". I want to see my changes in js files when I refresh page. so I use gulp-watch please help to me ... thanks

this my code in gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task("MainProjectLibrary", function () {
    return gulp.src([
        "./Public/DragDrop.js",
        "app.js",
        "./Constants/Errors.js",
        "./Constants/Message.js",
        "./Constants/APIControllerName.js",
        "./Controllers/AppController.js",
        "./Services/AppService.js",
        "./Services/ReportService.js",
        "./Filters/cutTextFilter.js",
        "./Filters/enumlistFilter.js",
        "./Filters/jalaliDateFilter.js",
        "./Filters/checkForNumber.js",
        "./Factories/ModalFactory.js",
        "./Directives/clickAnywhereDirective.js",
        "./Directives/numbersOnlyDirective.js",
        "./Scripts/angucomplete-alt.js",
        "./Scripts/datePicker.js",
        "./Modals/ModalTradeController.js",
        "./Modals/ModalDepositController.js",
        "./Modals/ModalPeymentRequest.js",
        "./Modals/ModalChangeBroker.js",
        "./Modals/AlertController.js",
        "./Modals/CreateNoteController.js",
        "./Modals/DeleteController.js",
        "./Modals/EditNoteController.js",
        "./Modals/NewMarketWatchController.js",
        "./Modals/EditMarketWatchController.js",
        "./Modals/ShowSettingController.js",
        "./Modals/DivideOrderController.js",
        "./Modals/EditNoteSymbolMessagesController.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Services/DashboardService.js",
        "./Modules/MarketDepth/Controllers/MarketDepthController.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Services/DepositService.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Controllers/PaymentRequestController.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Services/PaymentRequestService.js",
        "./Modules/Public/Controllers/SymbolMessageController.js",
        "./Modules/Public/Controllers/ChangePasswordController.js",
        "./Modules/Public/Services/ChangePasswordService.js",
        "./Modules/Reports/Controllers/TradeOrdersController.js",
        "./Modules/Reports/Services/TradeOrdersService.js",
        "./Modules/Reports/Services/AccountTransactionService.js",
        "./Modules/Portfolio/Controllers/PortfolioController.js",
        "./Modules/Portfolio/Services/PortfolioService.js",
        "./Modules/MarketDepth/Services/MarketDepthService.js",
        "./Modules/MarketDepth/Controllers/MarketDepthController.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Controllers/ChangeBrokerController.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Controllers/DashboardController.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Controllers/DepositController.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Controllers/PaymentRequestController.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Services/ChangeBrokerService.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Services/DashboardService.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Services/DepositService.js",
        "./Modules/Dashboard/Services/PaymentRequestService.js",
        "./Modules/Public/Services/SymbolMessageService.js",
        "./Modules/Reports/Controllers/AccountTransactionController.js"
    ])
        .pipe(concat("MainProjectLibrary.min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./Dist/"));
});

gulp.task("default", function() {
    return gulp.watch("./Dist/*.min.js", gulp.series("MainProjectLibrary"));
});
```

and this is my terminal after run task default. task not finishing 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the previous problem is solved easily just by changing the version of the gulp from 4x to 3x.